# Why the plot appears differently between the x-axis use date and the x-axis use list of numbers on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have stock data that contains the ohlc attribute and I want to make a `RSI` indicator plot by calculating the close value. Because the stock data is sorted by date, the date must be changed to a number using `date2num`. But the calculation result of the close attribute becomes a list of `RSI` values when plotted overlapping.

I think the length of the results of the RSI is not the same as the date length, but after I test by doing `len(rsi) == len(df ['date'])` show the same length. Then I try not to use the x-axis date but the list of number made by `range(0, len(df['date']))` and plot show as I expected.

```py
#get data
df = df.tail(1000)

#covert date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(mdates.date2num)

#make indicator wit TA-Lib
rsi = ta.RSI(df['close'], timeperiod=14)

#plot rsi indicator wit TA-Lib
ax1.plot(df['date'], rsi)
ax2.plot(range(0, len(df['date'])), rsi)

#show chart
plt.show()
```

I expect the output using the x-axis date to be the same as the x-axis list of numbers

[Image that shows the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLDGU.png)

Comment: Please convert your question into a [minimal, working and testable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have edited it more simply, I hope it's easier to understand.

Comment: It looks cleaner already. But the goal is really to post something that others can directly run on their computer (for example to test reproducibility). Currently, this is still not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that matplotlib chooses the x-ticks to display (when chosen automatically) to show "round" numbers. So in your case of integers, a tick every 200; in your case of dates, every two months.

You seem to expect the dates to follow the same tick steps as the integers, but this will cause the graph to show arbitrary dates in the middle of the month, which isn't a good default behavior.

If that's the behavior you want, try something of this sort:

```
rng = range(len(df['date']))
ax2.plot(rng, rsi)  # Same as in your example
ax2.set_xlim((rng[0], rng[-1]))  # Make sure no ticks outside of range
ax2.set_xticklabels(df['date'].iloc[ax2.get_xticks()])  # Show respective dates in the locations of the integers
```

This behavior can of course be reversed if you wish to show numbers instead of dates, using the same ticks as the dates, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

After I tried several times, I found the core of the problem. On weekends the data is not recorded so there is a gap on the date. The matplotlib x-axis date will be given a gap on weekends even though there is no data on that day, so the line plot will overlap.

For the solution I haven't found it, but for the time being I use the list of numbers.